# Issue With Isset() Function

Tags: php, isset

Trying to learn PHP with test and try method I am struggling with isset().
Here is the code I have:

```
<form action="validate.php" method="POST">
  <label title="User Input"> Custom Header Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="user_input">
  <button  type="submit" id="pageName">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and PHP file is as

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['user_input']))
    {
     echo "Input Is Set";
    } else{
           echo "Not Yet Set";
          }
?>
```

I both cases(empty or filled input) I am getting the first message "Input Is Set" as result!
Can you please let me know why this is happening?

Comment: Pretty sure thats because even if its not filled out its still sending an empty post of user_input. isset only checks for existence not content.

Comment: Hola lemondrop, but I test the isset() function with a litral php variable like $name; and it was working fine howcome is not working here

Comment: Just check the answers they have what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `user_input` have `isset` once form is submitted also if it is not filled, to avoid the error simply add an `!empty` check

```
if(isset(($_POST['user_input'])) && (!empty($_POST['user_input'])))
```

Comment: exactly what I was typing up.

Comment: Hi Fabio, Thanks for reply.Honestly I didn't want to validate the input now. In fact my question is if the isset() function is to check if variable has been set or not?! why it is not working here then?

Comment: @MonaCoder As i told you this is because also if it is not filled it is still sending an empty value when form is submitted, because of that isset() will be true so really need to check if is different from empty.

Comment: Thanks I think I get it , but can you please let me know what exactly the "empty value" is? do you mean NULL? can we print it out?

Comment: Try to `var_dump($_POST['user_input']);`, see by yourself

Answer (score 1):

Instead of isset, you can do this:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['user_input']))
    {
    if (!empty($_POST['user_input'])) {
      echo "Input Is Set";
    } else {
      echo "Input is empty!";
    }
  } else{
   echo "Not Yet Set";
  }
?>
```

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
<?php
  if($_POST['user_input'] != '')
    {
     echo "Input Is Set";
    } else{
           echo "Not Yet Set";
          }
?>
```

Or else use `if (!empty($_POST['user_input'])`

Check to see if it holds any value. That should work

Comment: and it will be notice if it's not set :)

Answer (score 0):

You check if it's set but you should check also if it's empty.

**Short version:**

```
<?php
  echo isset($_POST['user_input']) && !empty($_POST['user_input'] ? "Input is set" : "not set";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommed you to work with strlen() for 2 reasons:

```
if (strlen($_POST['user_input']) > 0 && strlen($_POST['user_input']) < 80)
{ ... }
```

1. you can be sure the variable is not just set, but also it does actually contain data
2. you should cap strings from POST and GET to avoid long injected queries for example.

best is to make your own wrapper for security and isset checks in a little helper function.