# Super basic PHP issue with ISSET

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to use some basic PHP to capture some form information on a website.

I used the PHP and HTML from [this site](http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php), and am getting this error:

```
"Format Error on line 3: parse error, unexpected T_IF(if)!" error:
```

I've tried to explore what could be causing this, and I know it has something to do with checking if the "email" variable is empty or not. I tried using the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781384/issue-with-isset-function) (checking with !empty), and a few other things I found online but nothing has worked yet.

Any help would be appreciated!

The problem area of the code is at the very beginning (added the end of the code as well):

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {



// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

$email_to = "you@yourdomain.com";

$email_subject = "Your email subject line";



...



// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>



<!-- include your own success html here -->



Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.



<?php

}

?>
```

Comment: You should copt the exact code in here.

Comment: It's probably because you copied it from that site and there's weird unicode characters in there. Type it yourself, verbatim, and it will work. Stupid color coding.

Comment: @Rudie Why are unicode characters weird?!?

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: @rudie Sure. Added code snippet to main question.

Comment: I'm pretty that you haven't close the if condition with "}" in the right place.

Comment: most of the time the error is about missing semicolon `;` or as Martialp said, u missed closing braces `}`

Comment: @Martialp I added the end of the PHP as well, which is where the closing "}" is. Does that help?

Comment: remove the `...` thhree dots from ur code, under `$email_subject`

Comment: @Bsienn Sorry I should have clarified--I added those as a placeholder for all the code in between the beginning and end. They are not there in the actual code. The full actual code can be seen through the link I posted.

Comment: everything looks good to me then.

Comment: i just copied the code from the link u provided, and everything works good.

Comment: frustrating. well thanks anyways @Bsienn I'll keep messing with it.

Comment: @Bsienn Would it not have anything to do with the fact that the closing "}" is after the PHP is closed and opened again?

Comment: no  ur clossing `}` is at right places in sense that it will not effect ur program, the code is fine, maybe u r doing something else making the code break. provide complete code in `paste` so we can see. i guess u r in localhost right?

Comment: @arkascha Unicode characters that look look white space to humans, break PHP compilers. because they aren't white space. If `if` comes after a fake white space, PHP complains. I'm still pretty sure it's that.

Comment: @LeeLK Just do as I said: remove the first 3 lines and type them manually. Voila. (Or the parse error is now on line 5 or something.)

Comment: @Rudie Looks like you and Bsienn were right. I just deleted some whitespaces in the code and the error went away. It changed to a new error later in the file...but I'll keep updating the format and that should help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parse error you're getting has nothing to do with the contents of $_POST['email']. It's some kind of syntax error.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10860395/1419321

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just isset($_POST['email'])? Can you please upload you php file to somewhere so i can try it on my pc?